# Why isn't silence just zeroes in an audio file, and how can I make it?

Tags: audio, sound

I'm completely new to the world of audio and signals. I noticed that when I opened Audacity and generated one second of silence (details below) and converted the raw WAVE file to a list of integers, that the silence wasn't a bunch of zeroes. (Yes, I was sure to convert the endianness.)

It was a series of seemingly random numbers from -7 to +7. (It was 16-bit signed PCM.)

Generated by:

- Open Audacity
- Click Generate > Silence...
- Set duration to 00h00m01.000s
- Click OK
- Click File > Export > Export as WAV
- Enter a file name
- Specify encoding as "signed 16-bit PCM"
- Click Save
- Open the generated file with a program that lists each chunk as a list of signed 16-bit integers
- (Optional) Convert little-endian words to big-endian words

My guess is that it is because a constant value, which is ideal DC, is equivalent to 0 Hz, and that's too low of a frequency for a speaker to produce, so it generates negligible noise instead.

Anyway, I was wondering, how does Audacity generate silence? Is it random number generation in [-7, +7]? Is there a mathematical formula for the noise?

What is the algorithm for producing that "silence", as a list of 16-bit integers? (which I can easily convert into a WAVE file)

**Summary:**

- What algorithm does Audacity use / can I use to generate "silence"?

Comment: There is this (since 1990) commonly-used technique of [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) but that seems to be a little intense.  I would ***not*** expect dithering to be toggling the bottom 4 bits (which is what going from -7 to +7 is).  I would expect the bottom 2 bits to be toggling.  Like going from -1 to +1 with a few 0's in between.

Comment: Well, now we know what the Sound of Silence looks like, at least.

Comment: How did you "generate silence"?  Did you, perchance, record a second of input from an unplugged microphone jack or some such?

Comment: Yeah, happens for me too. I don't see a reason why it needs to happen, considering floats can represent 0 exactly. And the same happens even if I create the track at 16-bit PCM in Audacity. When I export as 32-bit float RAW, it gets all zeros though. [Related manual section](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/dither.html).

Comment: Audacity works internally with 32-bit floats. When you create silence it creates float zeros. What you see happens when you export the file to wave format. It applies "dithering" to decorrelate the quantization noise from the actual signal. See https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/dither.html

Comment: I don't see the "details below". How did you generate the silence?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson apparently, such an amplitude is required if the noise is high-pitched rather than white.

Comment: Well, @DmitriUrbanowicz ,  I know a thing or two about dither myself. And I know the difference and roles of the Probability Density Function (p.d.f.) and of the Spectral Density (a.k.a. Power Spectrum) is.  And they are different.  To completely decouple **both** the first and second moments of the quantization error (using a uniform quantizer) from the signal being quantized, triangular p.d.f. of width of two quantization steps is exactly enough.  Independent of the spectral density.

Comment: @TimWescott In Audacity: Generate > Silence... : Set duration to 00h00m01.000s > OK

Comment: @user253751 Yeah my bad, I was originally asking a different question that had the details and I mistakenly removed that part along with the other stuff I removed. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 19):

Full silence is just zeroes.

You likely generated the silence to an audio track which is in some other format than 16-bit PCM, like float or 24-bit or 32-bit PCM.

When you exported it as 16-bit wave file, the values need to be converted or truncated to 16-bits. That process may include dithering, so you likely have dithering enabled for conversions in the settings.

Either change the dithering settings, or use 16-bit format for the audio track.

So silence algorithm is not the problem here that would generate random noise, it's the dithering process used in conversions between formats.

Comment: So, essentially, my manually generated silence can just be zeroes because I don't have to worry about dithering since I'm working only with 16-bit values?

Comment: The generated values are likely zero, but they don't get exported as zeroes due to dithering done before export. If you expect and want zeroes, turn off dithering. But in practice, the dithered silence is better, because you at least get some data that's non-zero you can assume as PCM, so many audio DSPs are happier with that, because just having completely flat signal of "Zero PCM" means you can't expect that to be PCM and play it on speakers, if suddenly some bitstream audio appears (like on DVD, Bluray).

Answer (score 5):

> What algorithm does Audacity use / can I use to generate "silence"?

Insert zeros in the audio stream.

However:

Microsoft WAV (the typical format for files ending in `.wav`) is still a *container* format; so, what you think you were looking at (16 bit PCM samples) probably wasn't what you're actually looking at. The format is way more complex than what you'll find in books from 1993.

However, in your case, as Justme says: this is just (unnecessary) dithering happening.

> What is the algorithm for producing that "silence", as a list of 16-bit integers? (which I can easily convert into a WAVE file)

Generate zeros and save them using your preferred export tool for wave files. It would seem you're already doing that!

So, let's rephrase this to

> Knowing I just need to encapsulate zeros in a Microsoft WAV-compatible file, how do I do that?

Many approaches, because many tools and programming languages support writing to WAV files, and any reasonable language will support "vectors of zeros" in some form. But we can do it the very lazy Python way. If you haven't used python before: Paste this in a text file, save the text file (say, as `generatesilence.py`), go to the directory of that file, and run it (e.g., as `python3 generatesilence.py`)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import wave

# Open a (new if necessary) wave file for binary writing
outf = wave.open("silence.wav", "wb")

framerate = 48000 # or whatever you prefer
silenceduration = 60 # or how many seconds you want to produce
bytesperframe = 2 # 2 -> 16 bit

outf.setframerate(48000)
outf.setnchannels(1)
outf.setnframes(int(silenceduration * framerate))
outf.setsampwidth(bytesperframe)

outf.writeframes(
    bytes(
        0 for i in range(int(silenceduration * framerate) * bytesperframe)
    )
)
```

Note: from a developer's perspective, I'm almost certain you're planning to use this silence in some other system that reads a fixed set of audio formats. Really check whether you really want to use uncompressed PCM audio for that – feels like a huge waste of space (and speed, because compressed audio can typically decoded at a higher rate than your storage can read uncompressed audio). Many programs do just use a more versatile library (like `libsndfile`) for reading audio files and thus support all the modes of that, not just "1991-style Microsoft WAV", or "later-Windows Microsoft WAV" which can also contain compressed (but not variable-bitrate, so only lossy compression is possible) audio.

Comment: The process is correct; there is just dithering enabled by default so it does not end up as zeroes on the file.

Comment: yeah, that seems to be the case.

Comment: @Justme you're right, should have actually addressed the concern of OP; fixed that

Comment: The wave format as everyone uses it is **not** that complex. It **is** as simple as you'll find in books from 1993. In particular, there are no extra bytes in the middle of the audio data.

Comment: @user253751 personal experience tells me that the "simple" WAV interfaces Matlab and scipy.io already don't agree in a lot of cases, and that the code that was used in GNU Radio prior to release 3.9, which was really based on the win3.11 era WAV format specification, couldn't deal with many .WAV files that you actually encounter in the wild. So, my experience is different to yours!

Comment: Re: no extra bytes in the middle: that's true as long as your frame format is as expected. WAV can contain a lot of audio formats; basically anything the Microsoft Audio Compression Manager supports, which as mentioned only deals with constant-rate codecs. For a selection of WAV contained codecs, see: https://www.nch.com.au/acm/ you can put mp3 audio inside a WAV container!

Comment: @user253751 WAV file is a container. You can have it contain non-PCM formats such as MP3 too. It isn't that simple, unless you assume it must be uncompressed linear PCM.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations at the end of your answer. Currently, I'm just working with WAVE audio as a stepping stone. My end goal is definitely to use compressed audio of some kind, since I'm intending to pull some kind of embedded system application out of the library I'm writing.

Comment: @PatrickO'Brien then definitely take a look at libsndfile. We (as in: the GNU Radio Project) adopted (as in: drmpeg was the one doing all the work) libsndfile in our WAV file sink and source blocks. Formerly, we had a handwritten "classic" WAV file reader which failed on a lot of perfectly normal files, now we can read all WAV files we have encountered so far, as well as OPUS, vorbis, FLAC, and a few of other formats :)

Comment: @Justme literally nobody uses WAV format to store MP3-compressed data.

Comment: @user253751 No, but that was not the point. The point was, it is a container format to store anything, and you can store anything in it, as long as there is a format tag for it.